# C# search line and then overwrite it

Tags: c#

How can I find a line in C# and overwrite it (.sii file)?

```
string result = string.Empty;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("my_truck_placement: ("))
    {
        var text = line.Replace("my_truck_placement: ", "");
        result = text.Trim();
        File.WriteAllText(Path, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of yours is that you are trying to write to file too early, before you finish analyzing content of the file.

```
// use implicit types wherever possible
// Good to explicitly initiate with string.Empty :)
var result = string.Empty;

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path);

// I prefer here for each loop, as we are oging ot modify content of 
// collection being iterated over.
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var line = lines[i];
    if (line.Contains("my_truck_placement: ("))
    {
        lines[i] = line.Replace("my_truck_placement: ", "");
    }
}

// Here, after all manipulations, you are able to write to file.
File.WriteAllLines(Path, lines);
```

You could simplify even further, for example loop body:

```
lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("my_truck_placement: (", "(");
```

If you are sure the phrase will only happen at the beginning of the line.

You could even limit yourself to such code

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    Path, 
    File.ReadAllLines(Path)
        .Select(x => x.Replace("my_truck_placement: (", "("))
        .ToArray());
```

Comment: And where do I insert the nine coordinates? They are in a string and come after the "("

Comment: @user20433809 what cooridnates? i dont see anything like that in your question